# How generate ARM object file on linux

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux

I'm trying to generate ARM Object file under ubuntu using arm-none-eabi package but without success.

url describing this format:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/BCEJDJBC.html

```
root@ubuntu:~/arm/blink# arm-none-eabi-as hello.S 
root@ubuntu:~/arm/blink# file a.out 
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what the problem is? file output says it is an ARM object. So what exactly are you expecting or think is wrong?

Comment: @alan-au
Indeed it's ELF:

    root@ubuntu:~/arm/blink# hexdump -C -n 4 a.out 
    00000000  7f 45 4c 46                                       |.ELF|

and like u can see in documentation AOF (chunk format) should begin with magic value:
ChunkFileId == 0xC3CBC6C5 or 0xC5C6CBC3
and I want to achieve object file in that format.

Comment: Ok it wasn't clear you wanted AOF files. In that case why are you using the gnu toolchain which produces ELF files? You need to use the assembler provided within the arm Software Development Toolkit.Looks like its "armasm": http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/BCEJDJBC.html

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you'd want an ancient obsolete image format unless you're also using a 20-year-old toolchain to consume that obsolete image format, in which case that toolchain could be used to create such images, no? Maybe a bit more clarification would be in order.

Comment: I'm completely fresh in topic related with ARM / ARM toolchains, what;s ancient what's not but.... Object file in such specific format is necessary for me to continue some research related with this file format, that's why I'm insisting to achieve .o file in that form.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the [up-to-date ARM object format](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044e/index.html).

Comment: @user3305379 Are you sure you want that format? *ALL* linux objects are .o files. Did someone ask you to compile an "arm object"? If so, it is likely they meant the "ELF ARM object" file as it is so common that people don't even need to say "ELF", just "ARM object". So unless you have specifically been asked to use the old AOF format I would check to make sure you aren't going down the wrong track,

Comment: Indeed - note that [the very documentation set referred to](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/Chdbihhi.html) describes AIF as deprecated and states "Future versions of the ARM Linker will output images only in ELF file format." And that was in 1998.

Comment: Thank You guys for all the comments. Indeed I need the object file to be exactly in that form like this one presented in documentation pointed by my above. Really, it does not matter whether is old school format and currently nobody use it. My research is strictly related with that format I just need file with that structure. So generally if somebody has example just throw the url, don't need to produce my own one.